# Problemas para usar colores con la función print en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, color

quiero usar colores en mi formato de salida del terminal de python para la función print. 
He probado los siguientes códigos:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print('\033[1;41mHighlighted Red like Radish\033[1;m')
print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Success!' + '\x1b[0m')
prt = "Hello world!"
print("\033[94m {}\033[00m" .format(prt))
print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n")
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Cómo veís también he probado importando el módulo colorama pero nada.
En internet, googleando parece haber mucha información al respecto, el problema es que parece un poco desfasada porque print ya no es una instrucción sino una función.
Mi versión de python es la 3.4.4 y la de mi IDLE es 3.4.3

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la idea de esto es usarlo en la terminal/CMD mediante secuencias de caracteres de escape ANSI, el IDLE es una aplicación (hecha en Tkinter) , no una terminal propiamente dicha. ¿Has probado el script ejecutándolo en la terminal? ¿Que sistema operativo y que shell usas?

Comment: @FJSevilla: XP y cmd

Comment: Por desgracia no puedo testear el código en XP, prueba con el siguiente import: `from colorama import init Fore, Back, Style` y en la siguiente línea : `init(convert=True)`. Funciona en Windows 10 tanto en cmd como en Power Shell, en XP lo desconozco. Si te funciona por un casual comentlalo y creo una respuesta más detallada. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla:He hecho lo que me has dicho. Funciona en el cmd, lo he probado con w7. Supongo que también funcionará en xp. Si, formula una respuesta para que pueda validarla y por favor, especifica en tu respuesta  que la solución no es válida para el entorno del IDLE ya que parece que no hay manera que funcione con este.

Comment: Mr. Baldan ya la he creado, he incluido lo comentado aquí un poco más extendido y he dejado una nota sobre el IDLE (en realidad esto pasa con cualquier otro entorno de desarrollo). He visto tu otra pregunta sobre como hacer esto en el IDLE especificamente, cuando tenga algo de tiempo voy a mirarme un poco la implementación y documentación del IDLE a ver si es posible sin tener que retocar el código fuente del programa, aunque a priori creo que no es posible. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Windows, CMD tradicionalmente no ha soportado las secuencias de escape ANSI sin usar algún parche externo. Para que ***colorama*** funcione adecuadamente en CMD/PowerShell es necesario usar la clase `init` y fozar la conversión de las secuencias de escape ANSI a llamadas legitimas al api Win32. De la [documentación](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) oficial de `**colorama**`:

> On Windows, calling init() will filter ANSI escape sequences out of any text sent to stdout or stderr, and replace them with equivalent Win32 cal.

Traducción libre:

> En Windows, al llamar a `init ()` se filtrarán las secuencias de escape ANSI de cualquier texto enviado a `stdout` o `stderr`, y se reemplazarán con llamadas `Win32` equivalentes.

El siguiente código es válido y está probado en Windows 7, 8, 10, debería funcionar también en XP y otras distribuciones Windows:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init

init(convert = True)

print('\033[1;41mHighlighted Red like Radish\033[1;m')
print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Success!' + '\x1b[0m')
prt = "Hello world!"
print("\033[94m {}\033[00m" .format(prt))
print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n")
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota importante:**
>
> Hay que tener en cuenta que ***colorama*** está pensado para ser usado en terminal (Windows y todas aquellas consolas Unix-like que soporten secuencias de escape ANSI). Esto implica que el código no va a funcionar en principio en las consolas implementadas en los distintos entornos de desarrollo o intérpretes interactivos. Es decir, no funcionará en la consola o intérprete interactivo del IDLE, terminales de Eric, Eclipse, etc.