# Usar colores con la función print en el IDLE de Python

Tags: python, color

Me preguntaba si hay alguna solución para usar colores con la función print y que se visualicen en IDLE al ejecutar el programa.
He encontrado algo de información al respecto en [este enlace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq7sq.png)

```
import sys

try:
    shell = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError:
    raise RuntimeError("you must run this program in IDLE")

shell.write("Wanna go explore? ","KEYWORD")
shell.write("OPTIONS","STRING")
shell.write(" : ","KEYWORD")
shell.write("Yes","DEFINITION")
shell.write(" or ","KEYWORD")
shell.write("No","COMMENT")
```

El código anterior funciona pero parece que son tipos ya definidos y no puedes definir tu el color.

¿Existe alguna forma alternativa a esta que menciono de mostrar colores con la función print en el IDLE de python?
¿Si no existe, puedo eligir los colores usando la forma que menciono (usando el módulo sys) en vez de que me vengan predefinidos?

Por cierto mi versión de IDLE es 3.4.3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el Idle "de fabrica" no es posible colorear la salida. El código que adjuntas (por cierto de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108559/how-to-print-colour-color-in-python) pregunta) es un "hack" para colorear de alguna forma el output de cualquier Script en Idle. En realidad lo que se hace es asociar cada texto a un keyword/tag del resaltado de sintaxis propio de Idle, el color puede modificarse pero solo en el marco global del tema usado en el resaltado de sintaxis: Menu Options - Configure Idle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta, además, que usar este truco así como está solo funcionaría en Idle, si corremos el Script por linea de comandos / shell directamente no funcionará. Para colorear la salida en terminal hay varias librerías que ya te han mencionado, pero funcionan solo en la terminal no sobre Idle (incluso en algunos casos es complicado/imposible sobre la línea de comandos de Windows), si quieres colorear el output en Idle de manera más controlada creo que la única alternativa es "extender" alguna de las clases del propio Idle (Por ej. en ColorDelegator podrías agregar nuevos "tags" y configuraciones para cada color que quieras usar)

Por cierto dudé un poco si ésta no es una pregunta duplicada de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99183/problemas-para-usar-colores-con-la-funci%C3%B3n-print-en-python) en la cual ya tienes una muy buena respuesta que bien podría aplicarse también en esta pregunta.

Comment: No pretendía ser una pregunta duplicada, quería hacerla específica sobre el IDLE. La otra pregunta es más general.

Comment: Lo comentaba por que es una pregunta interesante, y la respuesta de @FJSevilla en la anterior era buena y responde en buena medida a esta también. Tal vez convenga unificarla y dejar una sola. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias posibilidades puedes informarte en las siguientes guías:

- Mira en [Python termcolor module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor), un ejemplo:

  ```
  from termcolor import colored as colorear

  print colorear('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
  ```

Sin embargo no funciona en windows, te sirve si usas otro OS.

- Puedes usar [Colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) de python.

  ```
  import colorama
  from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

  colorama.init()

  text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

  print(Fore.RED + text)
  print(Back.GREEN + text + Style.RESET_ALL)
  print(text)
  ```

Tampoco funciona en windows, especifica si es la plataforma que necesitabas.